# ¿como hacer una tabla con columnas en Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, vue.js, vuex

Tengo que desarrollar un componente para mostrar el resumen de una venta: (Adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y solamente tengo este codigo inicial

```
<b-list-group>
                          <b-list-group-item variant="light">Subtotal</b-list-group-item>
                          <b-list-group-item variant="light">Descuento</b-list-group-item>
                          <b-list-group-item variant="light">Envío</b-list-group-item>
                          <b-list-group-item variant="light">Impuesto</b-list-group-item>
                          <b-list-group-item variant="light">Total</b-list-group-item>
```

y **lo que necesito es hacerlo asi como se ve en la imagen en principio**.

Comment: Hola,la tabla la puedes maquetar con bootstrap?

Comment: Si, con bootstrap @SebastiánMiranda

Comment: Mi respuesta es solo maquetación pero encontré este link que está mucho mejor [LINK](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html),

Comment: muchas gracias @SebastiánMiranda me sirve mucho tu aporte!

Comment: como ayuda, ve tutoriales de como crear un template en vue, no es complicado, porque el html de la tabla que te pasé puede ir ahí y tu ya hacer el lado de la programación con Vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno si puedes hacer la tabla con bootstrap, puede ser así:

```css
.fondo{
  background: #dbd7ce;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div class="row col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">

    <table class="table col-sm-4">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="fondo">Subtotal</th>
          <td>25000</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"class="fondo">Descuento</th>
          <td>15%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="fondo">Envío</th>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="fondo">Impuesto</th>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="fondo">TOTAL</th>
          <td class="fondo">45.000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```